# Market Equilibrium & Calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, economics

I am a math nerd, but I'm working on my majorly lacking derivative analysis calculus. Trying to break into better understanding market equilibrium. I found some example questions that I am working through.

**DEMAND: 344 - 2x**

**SUPPLY: 80 + 4x**

The questions:

**1. What are the value of the equilibrium price and quantity?** I already devised 44 as the value of x, is this the answer to both price and quantity, or just one of them?

**2. How exactly would graph these two functions by hand?** Kind of a vague question, but I'm unsure how a function like this actually graphed.

**3. The value of surplus at equilibrium quantity is $___?**
Based on this question I am assuming that the 256 I devised for x is the quantity, not the price/value?

**4. At what price would there be a surplus of 50?**
Completely lost here, but I am assuming you use the original formulas in some manner.

Not for school or any sort of homework, just for personal knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: For getting a rough sketch of the graphs by hand, [read this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/graph-transformation/).

Comment: You'll need to have a starting graph to use that technique. The graph $y=x$ is pretty simple to draw. Use that as a starting point to sketch the two graphs.

Comment: If you don't tell us whether $x$ is price or quantity, we cannot know whether $x$ is price or quantity.  As a general rule, demand and supply are written as functions of price, which suggests that $x$ is price.  But as another general rule, price tends to be denoted $P$ while quantity tends to be denoted $Q$ or $x$, which suggests that $x$ is quantity.  Only the poser of the question (i.e. you) can reconcile this.

Comment: @WillO, you are saying that if the formulas were written as Q = 344 - 2p we would be calculating the price, since P were used? Therefore in this case, the quantity would be 256 and the price would be 44?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, I will look through that article. Graphing as a whole isn't too complicated in my eyes, I guess I'm just unsure of the first steps in determining the starting point.

Comment: @user3223880, as I said, to start, use the graph $y=x$ which I believe is quite simply to draw (a straight line through $(0,0)$ making an angle of $45^\circ$ with the positive $x$-axis).

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, Ah, now I understand. Sorry for confusion. Any idea how question 3 or 4 are answered?

Comment: For #3, the height of the triangle of surplus is the difference between the two price intercepts, and the base of that triangle is the equilibrium quantity.  Surplus = base x height/2.